# iOS Swift3 TextView line at wrong position

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a textView which i use as an input field for chatMessages. I want it to expand if there is more text than could fit in one row.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.textViewHeight.constant = textView.contentSize.height
}
```

I set a height constraint programmatically if the user enters something inside the textView.

[image] <- For one liners it looks fine.

[image] <- After you press enter it gets hidden.

[image] <- The second enter shows it up again.

What am i doing wrong here? I try to recreate the look of whatsapp / imessage, where this hiding does not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are changing the size in the wrong delegate function. The delegate `textViewDidChange` is called after you finished editing (resignFirstResponder gets called).

You should put your code to change the height in this function instead:

```
optional func textView(_ textView: UITextView, 
    shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, 
       replacementText text: String) -> Bool
```

So this will change the height of the `UITextView` as you type not after you finished typing.

Comment: This works fine except for pressing return, where it still gets hidden. It looks like one line breakage is not recognized. Do you know a way to fix this too?

Comment: Can you try putting some margins like `self.textViewHeight.constant = textView.contentSize.height + 10`